# My csv export displaying html, how to get rid of?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export-to-csv

I've seen this asked before and I am having trouble getting this to work properly after trying a number of solutions. The problem is I can't get my data to export into a csv format properly. Before I added my ob_end_clean it would export out to a csv with html, now it doesn't give me a csv, just text.

Here is my code on the file that is being required.

```
if (isset($_POST["hidden"])) {

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

    $fp = fopen('php://output','w');

    foreach ($list as $row) {
        ob_end_clean();
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

}
```

Right now when I do my export, the data gets put back on the screen similar to a var_dump(). I just simply want this to go to a csv file without having html all over it.

Comment: Do you have raw HTML before this code snippet? Did you try moving the ob_end_clean() before the foreach / CSV output?

Comment: Yeah I have a require on another file which echos back some html.

Comment: Well you should only do one thing, either generate a HTML page **or** output CSV. Move the CSV code to a separate script.

Comment: I've put it in a separate script before anything else. Now in my code, I took out the ob_end_clean and it works, but the html is still there. With it in there. I get errors.

Comment: Not just a separate php file, but a separate script, with a separate invokation point. No HTML templates in its path. Do you invoke the URL `outputcsv.php` or whatever directly or not? If not, do so.

Comment: Like mario said, if you're spitting out any HTML in the same file as the one you're trying to set the headers on, it's going to taint your csv file.  The header declaration should come before anything else gets echoed, and you shouldn't having any other HTML in the page, just straight php and csv data.

Comment: Thanks guys! I got it working. I invoked the my csv code before anything on the page. :) Then I did my connection to my table, then did my logic for my code. I didn't have an ob_start or ob_flush on my main file which made a big difference. I had the ob_clean before the while loop and then I did an exit() after declaring the header. Hopefully, this explains it well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Got it working!

I invoked my csv code before anything on the page. :) Then I did my connection to my table, then did my logic for my code. I didn't have an ob_start or ob_flush on my main file which made a big difference. I had the ob_clean before the while loop and then I did an exit() after declaring the header. Hopefully, this explains it well.

Here is my code.

```
if (isset($_POST["hidden"])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `newsletter`";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    ob_end_clean();

    $fp = fopen('php://output','w');

    while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        fputcsv($fp, $list);
    }

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. You saved my day.

Answer (score 5):

Place, ob_end_clean(); before you output the csv.

ob_end_clean() meaning: 
"Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering" - PHP manual.

Answer (score 2):

The logic for it to work is to construct your php script so that it:

1. first echoes all the html/javascript... content intended for the browser page like `echo "<html...>;"` (this already uses php's output buffer behind the scenes)
2. after that cleans the php's output buffer so far, with `ob_end_clean()` (depending how ob_start() was called this may prevent the previous export) or `ob_clean()` which just sends content so far to the browser and cleans the buffer without turning it off.
3. lastly uses this clean output buffer again to export any further content (as downloadable csv in our case) to the browser, like shown above by wowzuzz. So if any html is echoed by the script after that, it will be included in the csv as well.